# How to use nice modern google translate toolbar on my website

Tags: responsive, google-translate

I'm offering automatic Google translation to the users of my website using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15612915/5710912) method. However, Google Translate toolbar that shows up looks quite old-fashioned, like 15 years old and it even is not responsive for mobile users.

[image: Old-fashioned Google Translate toolbar]

When I translate whatever website pasting the link directly to google translate.google.com, then clicking on the result website redirects me to translate.goog website where I get much better toolbar that looks modern and is responsive (like [this](https://www-nytimes-com.translate.goog/?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=eo&_x_tr_hl=cs&_x_tr_pto=nui)). But the result is not on my website, it's on their servers.

[image: Modern Google translate toolbar]

Is there any way to tell Google to use this modern Google Translate UI directly on my website (using the method mentioned above)?